# Azure external Load balancer with AKS cluster

Tags: azure-aks, nginx-ingress, azure-load-balancer

I have created an Azure AKS cluster using Terraform, which automatically sets up a public IP and an external load balancer. Additionally, I have installed an nginx ingress that creates an internal load balancer. Currently, my Kubernetes services utilize this internal load balancer, and none of them are using the public load balancer.

I have a couple of questions regarding this setup:

1. Considering that the services are not utilizing the external load balancer, is it safe to delete it? How can I verify that the external load balancer is not being used anywhere?
2. Even though no load balancing rule has been added and the external load balancer is not being used, why do I see the AksOutboundBackendPool and Kubernetes listed in the backend pool settings?

I would appreciate clarification on these matters.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The load balancer is used for traffic egress from the cluster, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/egress-outboundtype

Load Balancer is the default, but there are other options.

In short, don't delete it, it is needed